# mysql server running on docker container remote connection shows lost connection to server during query

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a running docker mysql container that i have made container with this line of code :

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_pass -d -p 3308:3306 mysql
```

I could connect to database with navicat and copied my databse to it and at the time my back end server running on another docker container at tha same linux machine can connect and query database. problem is that my navicat suddenly cant connect to mysql server via 3308 port
the port is open in remote :

> docker-pr 80243 root    4u  IPv4 3912727      0t0  TCP *:3308 (LISTEN)
> docker-pr 80248 root    4u  IPv6 3912732      0t0  TCP *:3308 (LISTEN)

but now when i want to connect with navicat it shows this error :

> lost connection to server during query

after a while that i hit test connection on navicat.
intresting part is that the connection worked for couple of hours today and after that have problem again and i made no changes in remote machine,
any help whould be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error should be related to the `Socket Timeout` time that has a value too short for your query and you might increase it.

Please, take a look of the error form the [Navicat official documentation](https://help.navicat.com/hc/en-us/articles/217790688-2013-Lost-Connection-to-MySQL-server-during-query).

To modify the Socket timeout, try to:

- Control-click your connection and choose `Connection Properties/Edit Connection`
- Under `Advanced` tab, set the `Socket Timeout` (sec) to a larger value.